# Difference between different proxy types

Tags: vpn, proxy

While using VPN handler apps I have come across terms such as

- real host
- dual real host
- reverse proxy

These terms appear under the proxy type tab. What is the difference between them and what is their use while using proxy servers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the term real or dual real host but I'm assuming that means a normal (forward) proxy which essentially functions on behalf of one or more clients to shield their identity (among other purposes) from the internet at large.  The dual part is maybe a dual-homed proxy?  dual-homed means it has more than one network interface for redundancy.

As for reverse proxy it is the reverse of a forward proxy...it functions on behalf of the internal network of a collection of servers to make it appear as one single point is servicing clients when it may in fact be an entire network of servers providing services.